# Arduino Serial Monitor Input 3DES Encryption

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, array, bytes

I am trying to 3DES encryption using Serial Read, Found this 3DES Sample code in Github,

```
#include <DES.h>
DES des;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello!");
}
void loop() {
  desTest();
  tdesTest();
  delay(2000);
}
void desTest()
{
  byte out[8];
  byte in[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
  byte key[] = { 0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e };
  
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("========= DES test ==========");
  
  //encrypt
  Serial.print("Encrypt...");
  unsigned long time = micros();
  des.encrypt(out, in, key);
  time = micros() - time;
  Serial.print("done. (");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println(" micros)");
  printArray(out);
  
  //decrypt
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    in[i] = out[i];
  }
  Serial.print("Decrypt...");
  time = micros();
  des.decrypt(out, in, key);
  time = micros() - time;
  Serial.print("done. (");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println(" micros)");
  printArray(out);
}
void tdesTest()
{
  byte out[8];
  byte in[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
  byte key[] = { 
                  0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e, // key A
                  0x92, 0x2f, 0xb5, 0x10, 0xc7, 0x1f, 0x43, 0x6e, // key B
                  0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e, // key C (in this case A)
                };
  
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("====== Triple-DES test ======");
  
  //encrypt
  Serial.print("Encrypt...");
  unsigned long time = micros();
  des.tripleEncrypt(out, in, key);
  time = micros() - time;
  Serial.print("done. (");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println(" micros)");
  printArray(out);
  
  //decrypt
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    in[i] = out[i];
  }
  Serial.print("Decrypt...");
  time = micros();
  des.tripleDecrypt(out, in, key);
  time = micros() - time;
  Serial.print("done. (");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println(" micros)");
  printArray(out);
}
void printArray(byte output[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (output[i] < 0x10)
    {
      Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(output[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

I want to get user serial input from Serial Monitor to feed `byte in[]`. Which will encrypt user input, I will pad user input to 8 Bytes or restrict input to 8.

Library: https://github.com/Octoate/ArduinoDES

Could any one help me to get data from user input.

**Edit 1: I was able to read the String to char and feed to `byte in[]` changed the code,**

```
#include <DES.h>
DES des;

String  input;

char buf[30];
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello!");

}


void printArray(byte output[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (output[i] < 0x10)
    {
      Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(output[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}
void loop() {

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {

    String  input = Serial.readString(); // read the incoming data as string
    char buf[30];
/*
    input.toCharArray(buf, 9);
    Serial.println(buf);
*/
    input.toCharArray(buf, input.length() + 1);
    Serial.println(buf);

    
    byte out[8];
    byte in[] = {buf};
    Serial.println(buf);
    byte key[] = {
      0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e, // key A
      0x92, 0x2f, 0xb5, 0x10, 0xc7, 0x1f, 0x43, 0x6e, // key B
      0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e, // key C (in this case A)
    };

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("====== Triple-DES test ======");

    //encrypt
    Serial.print("Encrypt...");
    unsigned long time = micros();
    des.tripleEncrypt(out, in, key);
    time = micros() - time;
    Serial.print("done. (");
    Serial.print(time);
    Serial.println(" micros)");
    printArray(out);

    //decrypt
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      in[i] = out[i];
    }
    Serial.print("Decrypt...");
    time = micros();
    des.tripleDecrypt(out, in, key);
    time = micros() - time;
    Serial.print("done. (");
    Serial.print(time);
    Serial.println(" micros)");
    printArray(out);
    delay(2000);
  }


}
```

But I don't think getting the correct,
Please find the below,
[image]

But when I feed manually like below,

```
...
input.toCharArray(buf, input.length() + 1);
    Serial.println(buf);

    //tdesTest();
    byte out[8];
    byte in[] = {"12345678"}; //Manually feeding hardcoding the value need to get the value from serial read to here
    Serial.println(buf);
    byte key[] = {
      0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e, // key A
      0x92, 0x2f, 0xb5, 0x10, 0xc7, 0x1f, 0x43, 0x6e, // key B
      0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e, // key C (in this case A)
    };

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("====== Triple-DES test ======");
...
```

I get the expected output,

[image]

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Comment: Hi @Majenko, Thanks for the reply,  I can read the serial string from while (Serial.available > 0) {

    a = Serial.readString(); // read the incoming data as string
  } But I could not find a way to feed it to the "byte in[ ]" in tdesTest Method due to unable to feed the string.

Comment: Well, that all depends on what format your input is in and what format you need to feed into the `in` array.

Comment: I want to input `String` from Serial and convert it to `Char` and feed to `in[ ]` @Majenko

Comment: Yes, I gathered that. But *what is in the string*, and *how does that relate to what would be put into `in[]`*?

Comment: String is the data needs to be encrypted which will be feeds to `in [ ]` for encryption using DES Library.

Comment: `byte in[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };` will be replaced by `Char in [] = {Data_from_SerialRead}`

Comment: `a.c_str()` gives you a `char *` array pointer to the internal data buffer of the string. Is that what you are after?

Comment: @Majenko Thanks, Could you give me an example found this on internet but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I *think* I understand what you are after.  So, assuming you have read some string into a `String` object called `input` and you have an array `in[8]` to populate you can:

1. Clear the `in[]` array to a preset state
2. Copy the string content into `in[]`

As code:

```cpp
memset(in, 0, 8); // Erase the contents of in[]
input.toCharArray((char *)in, 8); // Copy up to 8 bytes from the string
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127135/discussion-on-answer-by-majenko-arduino-serial-monitor-input-3des-encryption).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <DES.h>
DES des;
byte in[8];
String  input;

char buf[30];
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello!");

}

void tdesTest() {
  byte out[8];


  byte key[] = {
    0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e, // key A
    0x92, 0x2f, 0xb5, 0x10, 0xc7, 0x1f, 0x43, 0x6e, // key B
    0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e, // key C (in this case A)
  };

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("====== Triple-DES test ======");

  //encrypt
  Serial.print("Encrypt...");
  unsigned long time = micros();
  des.tripleEncrypt(out, in, key);
  time = micros() - time;
  Serial.print("done. (");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println(" micros)");
  printArray(out);

  //decrypt
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    in[i] = out[i];
  }
  Serial.print("Decrypt...");
  time = micros();
  des.tripleDecrypt(out, in, key);
  time = micros() - time;
  Serial.print("done. (");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println(" micros)");
  printArray(out);
  delay(2000);
}


void printArray(byte output[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (output[i] < 0x10)
    {
      Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(output[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {

    String  input = Serial.readString(); // read the incoming data as string
    memset(in, 0, 9); // Erase the contents of in[]
    input.toCharArray((char *)in, 9); // Copy up to 8 bytes from the string
    tdesTest();


  }
}
```